# aligned malloc c++ implementation

Tags: c++, memory, malloc, heap-memory

I found this piece of code:

```
void* aligned_malloc(size_t required_bytes, size_t alignment) {
int offset = alignment - 1;
void* P = (void * ) malloc(required_bytes + offset);
void* q = (void * ) (((size_t)(p) + offset) & ~(alignment - 1));
return q;
}
```

that is the implementation of aligned malloc in C++. Aligned malloc is a function that supports allocating memory such that the
memory address returned is divisible by a specific power of two.
Example:

align_malloc (1000, 128) will return a memory address that is a multiple of 128 and that points to memory of size 1000 bytes.

But I don't understand line 4. Why sum twice the offset?

Thanks

Comment: Note that there is no way to free the memory allocated by this function, because the original address of the memory block has been thrown away.

Comment: What's the point? `malloc` already gives storage aligned for any scalar type. I would also stay away from any code which does convert to `void*` explicitly (especially given the fact that it is already return type from malloc!), same way you stay away from someone constantly biting their nails - it's just unsanitary. Last, why would you use malloc in C++?

Comment: @SergeyA -- it allows the user to specify the alignment, which is required for some kinds of operations. For example, DMA (I/O via direct memory access) might require a buffer with 512 byte alignment.

Comment: this example of code is insane, unsanitary and leads to UB , because any attempt to deallocate pointer that wasn't returned by malloc() would lead to undefined behavior. for C++ use there is `std::aligned_alloc` in C++17, `std::aligned_storage` in C++11, etc.,  otherwise there are better implementations that make use of platform specifics.

Comment: It's an exercise to understand the function of the malloc, do not focus on utility. I won't use it in real life :) P.S. You can find this piece of code in "Cracking the coding interview" book

Comment: @hteo: Never heard of that book. Throw it away. :-D (Personally, I have never been asked a "coding" question in an interview, and would cast a rather dim view on an interviewer who would. I'm interviewing for an engineering job, not as candidate in a quiz show. Examples of my work are available online, and a job interview should be about more important things than your skill at "coding on a whiteboard".)

Comment: !?!? it is one of the most famous (and best sellers) interviews preparation books...it is written by a person that had worked with Google, Apple...sorry. I also have a job, but that is a really cool and well written book about coding

Comment: @hteo: The code example you posted here tells a different story... also, they _want_ to sell those kind of books, don't they? I've talked in interviews about what an abstract class is and why you would use one, or about the concept of allocators... I have *never* been asked to be tricky with a couple of lines of code, or develop an algorithm _ad hoc_. Because _you should not be doing that_ in your work. You should _research_ prior art, find standard functions etc., instead of reinventing the wheel... the _broken_ wheel, in this case.

Comment: because it's an example. If you read the rest of the exercise always will be clear ;) There is also "what an abstract class is ". Believe me, this book is complete...

Comment: ...that example remains flirting with UB, being *really* bad C++ (architecture-wise, it's just not "how things should be done"), and rather questionable C as well. As such, I don't think it should be showvased by a good book.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie "any attempt to deallocate pointer that wasn't returned by malloc() would lead to undefined behavior". Could you elaborate or provide a reference?

Comment: @ChronoTrigger only valid pointer you can pass to free() are ones returned by  malloc, calloc and realloc, or  C11 aligned_alloc() , with calloc and realloc defined as wrappers around malloc(), realloc() frees its argument. The code above looks like a cheap attempt to implement C11's function without deferring to platform implementation of library\kernel memory manager. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why sum twice the offset?

**`offset` isn't exactly being summed twice.** First use of offset is for the size to allocate:

```
void* p = (void * ) malloc(required_bytes + offset);
```

Second time is for the alignment:

```
void* q = (void * ) (((size_t)(p) + offset) & ~(alignment - 1));
```

**Explanation:**
`~(alignment - 1)` is a *negation* of `offset` (remember, `int offset = alignment - 1;`) which gives you **the mask** you need to satisfy the alignment requested. Arithmetic-wise, adding the offset and doing *bitwise and* (`&`) with its negation gives you the address of the aligned pointer.

**How does this arithmetic work?** First, remember that the internal call to `malloc()` is for `required_bytes + offset` bytes. As in, not the alignment you asked for. For example, you wanted to allocate 10 bytes with alignment of 16 (so **the desired behavior is to allocate the 10 bytes starting in an address that is divisible with 16**). So this `malloc()` from above will give you `10+16-1`=25 bytes. Not necessarily starting at the right address in terms of being divisible with 16). But then this `16-1` is `0x000F` and its negation (`~`) is `0xFFF0`. And now we apply the *bitwise and* like this: `p + 15 & 0xFFF0` which will cause every pointer `p` to be a multiple of 16.

**But wait, why add this offset of `alignment - 1` in the first place?** You do it because once you get the address `p` returned by `malloc()`, **the one thing you cannot do** (in order to find the nearest aligned address) is look for it *before* `p` -- as this will cross outside the memory range allocated by the `malloc()` call, beginning at `p`. For this, you begin by **adding** `alignment - 1`, which, think about it, is exactly **the maximum by which you'd have to advance** to get your alignment.

* Thanks to user DevSolar for some additional phrasing.

Note 1: For this way to work the alignment must be a power of 2. This snippet does not enforce such a thing and so could cause unexpected behavior.

Note 2: An interesting question is how could you implement a `free()` version for such an allocation, with the return value from this function.

Comment: "Arithmetic-wise, adding the offset and doing bitwise and (&) with its negation gives you the address of the aligned pointer." why? Can you give me an example? P.S. About Note 2 there is another exercise for that

Comment: @hteo I added an edit to the answer, specifying the bitwise arithmetic. Let me know if it's good enough, we can always go deeper into the explanation, I just wanted to avoid an overbearing answer.

Comment: Thanks, is almost clear. When you do "p + 15 & 0xFFF0", p is 25?The result of last malloc?

Comment: @hteo so for any pointer p, `p & 0xFFF0` will be a multiple of 16. Easily you can see that as the first 0x000F (15) are "cancelled out". I'll edit the answer to make it clearer and let you know.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @hteo let me know if this is still unclear. I think it may have been a bit of as an explanation prior to last edit.

Comment: @hteo: The main idea here is this: To get align-16, you might have to move the address forward a maximum of 15 bytes. That's the `align - 1` value additionally allocated, because you can *only* move forward, not backward. *Getting* the aligned address is then done by adding the maximum value, and "rounding it off" by applying that bit mask.

Comment: @DevSolar that's a good way of putting it friend. I'll try adding some phrasing to the answer, inspired by it.